# list all the value from table and query the actual value for the integer column and display in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have three columns in my table `School`:

`id->int,
 name->string,
 status->int`

I have been using the value from `dropdown` to fill in the value in `status`, the array is static and it is only used on `view`:

```
{!! Form::select('status', ['1' => 'Active', '2' => 'In Active'], '1', ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Please Select Dean']); !!}
```

Now i wanted to list the value from `School` on table.

I have been using:

```
public function index()
{
    $title = 'School Info';
    $schoolList = School::all();

    return view('school.index',compact('schoolList','title'));
}
```

Index View

```
 <td></td>
 <td>{!!$school->name!!}</td>
 <td>{!!$school->status!!}</td>
```

This will return `status=1 or 2` on `view`. However, in table i want to use status=Active or In Active, by querying with the static variable array.

There is no relation between school and status currently.

How can i query for Status and Display the actual status value on table but not the integer value?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting (int) in the blade, you can do something like this in the blade

```
// In Blade.....

<td>{!! $school->status == "1" ? "Active" : "In Active" !!)</td>
```

Comment: Excellent solution! But, also how it is done in the controller?

Comment: ohh that "use DB;" right after the namespace deceleration (Top of the file)

Comment: should return `view('school.index',compact('users','title'));` right? But, got same value with number in `blade`

Comment: Then there is only thing left "MODEL RELATIONSHIP"

Comment: you can remove your second solution! first one will work for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188840/discussion-between-vipertecpro-and-akshaykriti).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Accessors if you are saving the status value as 1 or 0 like integer:

[image]

In your case write the codes in School model,

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value)
{
     if($value == 1){return 'Active';}
     if($value == 0){return 'InActive';}
     return $value; //if your status value is not 1 or 0 it will return the exact value of status
}
```

Now, If you use,

```
<td>{!!$school->status!!}</td>
```

in blade file it will display like Active or InActive

Comment: this is not a good solution! if we want `int` value from `status` to be bind on drop down it will not get bind because `getStatusAttribute` will convert that to string